# Discord bot not responding (python)

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('token is here')
```

I'm trying to create a discord bot and I'm trying to use this simple code to get started but whenever I type the command ($hello) in a server that the bot is in it doesn't respond. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're new to discord.py which is fine, though writing code like this is a little counter-intuitive. Instead of registering it as an event, why not just register it as an actual command?

This is how it should be done:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$') # This can always be changed

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def hello():
    await ctx.send('Hello')

client.run('token is here')
```

Comment: I tried that but the bot still doesn't respond when I start it up or when I send $ or $hello... I just strated with making discord bots so I'm not really sure how this works lol

Comment: turns out it wasn't a code problem but a discord bot thing because i needed to enable a setting in the bot section of my application that's supposedly a new thing lol

Comment: @RaymondLiu oh right, yeah that's intents. I completely forgot to mention that, I haven't wrote a Discord bot in a fair while.